# Running total of a measure which use DATESINPERIOD and months from fact table

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, powerpivot

I am using a measure below to display the months from fact table as described [here](http://sqljason.com/2018/03/display-last-n-months-selected-month-using-single-date-dimension-in-power-bi.html):

```
Billings12Months =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Datatable'[Allowable] ),
    DATESINPERIOD ( DimDate[Date], MIN ( DimDate[Date] ), +12, MONTH )
)
```

My attempt to get the running total of above measure is failing:

```
BillingsRunningTotal =
CALCULATE (
    [Billings12Months],
    FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate ), DimDate[Date] <= MAX ( DimDate[Date] ) )
)

BillingsRunningTotal2 =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[Date] ),
        DimDate[Date] <= MAX ( ( DimDate[Date] ) )
            && YEAR ( DimDate[Date] ) = YEAR ( MIN ( DimDate[Date] ) )
    ),
    [Billings12Months]
)
```

[BillingsRunningTotal] return same values as [Billings12Months] (please see screen 1 attached) and 
[BillingsRunningTotal2] return wrong values and month start from Jan, 17 instead of May, 17 (please see screen-2)

[image]
[image]

Please help me to calculate the running total. If possible please describe how your solution is working so that I can be better in DAX.

**Update:**

Please see the screen-3 below for the output when I use the measure suggested by Kosuke:

```
BillingsRunningTotal =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Datatable[Allowable] ),
    FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate ), DimDate[Date] <= MAX ( DimDate[Date] ) )
)
```

[image]
The months are from fact table (not from a Date table) and I think DATESINPERIOD plays a role to calculate and display the months. When we use SUM ( Datatable[Allowable] ), there would be a single month as dictated by the slicer. So we need to use DATESINPERIOD with rolling month calculation logic (DimDate[Date] <= MAX ( DimDate[Date] )) or virtually sum the [Billings12Months], It is where I am failing.

Thanks

Comment: If you are calculating rolling total of past 12 months with `Billings12Months`, then the third argument of `DATESINPERIOD` should be `-12` instead of `+12`. And I don't understand what you are trying to calculate with `BillingsRunningTotal`. Can you please update with a description about the desired output?

Comment: +12 is because I want future months of what has been selected in the 'Beginning of Fiscal Year' slicer, not the last 12 months and running total is just, for example, for Jul 17, it is 30,306.95 (May, 17) + 18,566.16 (Jun, 17).

Comment: thanks, I understood the Billings12Months. Based on the description, the running total for Jul 17 will be sum of total for May, 17 to Apr, 18 and total for Jun, 17 to May, 18, thus double-counting the value for Jun, 17 to Apr, 18. Is this understanding correct? What will the calculation be for different drill-down levels other than monthly? For example, if drilled down to daily level, should the number for Jul 3, 17 be total for Jul 1, 17 to June 30, 18 + total for Jul 2, 17 to Jul 1, 18?

Comment: No, the running total for July 2017 is simply May 17 + Jun 17 + July 2017, as a normal running total and the total is not required at the day level.

Comment: That totally makes sense. I will post an answer.

Comment: Please see the update in the question description.

Comment: It is a misconception that "DATESINPERIOD plays a role to calculate and display the months". DATESINPERIOD provides the date scope for what to be calculated. When calculating the rolling total for May 2017 for example, DATESINPERIOD can just tell that the measure should aggregate the facts in "May 2017 to Apr 2018". However, it cannot affect the visual to display the numbers for months other than May 2017.

Comment: Thanks, so what can be the DAX for running total and DATESINPERIOD combination.

Comment: Calculating running total is not a use case of DATESINPERIOD. The formula I have shown will just work. Make sure that the page filter covers the entire period to be displayed (e.g. year 2017), and use months of Calendar table for columns.

Comment: Well, if I had to use a Calendar table, I wouldn't have posted the question. There must be way to get running total from [Billings12Months] and the months from fact tables. I hope I will find a solution soon.

Comment: I cannot get the point why you cannot use Calendar table, even if you already have that... and given that there were some reason not to use calendar in the slicer, why not just replace DimDate[Date] with Datatable[Date] in the measure above (the one using 'SUM (Datatable[Allowable] )' )?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with the first attempt, however what to calculate is not [Billings12Months], but SUM( Datatable[Allowable] ).

```
BillingsRunningTotal =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Datatable[Allowable] ),
    FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate ), DimDate[Date] <= MAX ( DimDate[Date] ) )
)
```

Essentially, [Billings12Months] and [BillingsRunningTotal] are same in calculating the sum of Datatable[Allowable], but the only difference is each measure calculates for different scope of period. Therefore, the right way of thinking is to wrap SUM ( Datatable[Allowable] ) in CALCULATE, with different filter parameters.